# How to hold jenkins job when its already running in same or different jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've two Jenkins job - Jenkins Job1 and Jenkins Job2.

I've multiple application and using same jenkins to build the app. If same app is running in Jenkins - I would like put on hold till the previous build complete. How can we handle this scenario?

Thanks!

**Note:** We are using Jenkins Pipeline Job type

Comment: Do you think you could accept my answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

Two options here, using the lockable resource plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin)

*example usage:*

```
stage("Build Legacy"){
    steps{
        lock('Oracle-DB'){
            //with Bamboo SVN credentials, build using ant
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'credentials', variable: 'credentials')]) {
                sh "ant $BUILD_PROFILE -Dsvn.password=${env.credentials} -Dsvn.username=${credentials_name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any pipeline script looking to use that lock will have to wait for it to be released.

Or use disable concurrent builds. This only works if they are all being built in the same multi branch pipeline.

*example usage:*

```
options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
```

**PSA:**

Don't forget to create a retention policy or else you may run out of space pretty quickly. Add this one liner to your options declaration.

*example usage:*

```
buildDiscarder(logRotator(artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the option `Do not allow concurrent builds` in your job configuration if you don't want the same job to be executed twice at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running multiple application build using same Jenkins job. If want to restrict only if same application build is triggering again. For example: I've two application- App1 and App2. Assume that App1 build is trigger and in process if developer triggered the Jenkins job again App1 I would like to hold the build not Jenkins job because Jenkins job same for App1 and App2. Meanwhile if App 2 wants to build I should allow to trigger because App 2 build is triggering first time. How can we achieve this scenario

Comment: Do not allow concurrent builds will not stop multiple build projects from building on the same node. It will stop the same build project from building a second time. Just in case anyone needs that clarification.